# DNS delegation - is it possible to skip level?

Tags: dns

I need to create delegation to fourth level domain (something like fourth.third.example.com). The zone for the fourth level exists on the NS, but zone for the third doesn't.

Is it possible and correct to create delegation directly from second level zone to the fourth (skipping the third) like this?

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
..
..
fourth.third.example.com.   IN  NS  ns.example.com.
```

Or is it mandatory to create zone for each level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. As long as `third.example.com` is not already delegated in the same zonefile of course.

Note that delegation is not mandatory either. You can put all records directly in your zonefile as well. Delegation is useful only to give control of part of the tree to another set of nameservers, typically another administrative entity.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I've just tried it and it works. It's great to know that it's supposed to work (that it isn't working because some coincidence). Thank you very much for your answer!